# Use of infinitives in noun phrases

Tags: infinitives, noun-phrases

I know that we can use to-infinitives in a noun phrase outside a dependent clause, but can we use another type of infinitives, such as a bare infinitive? I can't think of any example for bare infinitives in noun phrases *outside* dependent clauses.

> Cars we see daily are not very special.

does not count because "see" is inside a dependent clause, "we see daily" with the "which omitted".

So is it possible?

==== EDIT ====

According to [britishcouncil](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/noun-phrase), which is more specific than wikipedia, the infinitive part of the noun phrase, if any, is a to-infinitive. No other option is given. However, I am not sure if it is over-simplifying it.

Comment: Is **see** an infinitive here? It can inflect, which an infinitive cannot. *Cars he **sees** daily are not very special*.

Answer (score 1):

By an infinitive in a noun phrase you mean:

> You should take *something to read*.

or

> You should force *me to run*.

then with the right choice of verb:

> You should help *me run*.

Other verbs that expect a bare infinitive include *let, make, see, hear, need*

Comment: Do they form a closed class?

Comment: Do you mean, is there a finite list of verbs which take a bare infinitive? Probably not, and some verbs (like help) can take either.   Note that modals are all followed by a bare infinitive, but modals are defective so it is normal to think of the infinitive as being part of the verb phrase.